# FTP Download File

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I am trying to file download from remote machine with FTP in c# but it doesn't work. when i came GetResponse Method with f10, threw the exception. its says:"unable to connect to remote server", it looks like about connection problem but its not.

when i create request in the code ContentType and PreAuthenticate is threw an exception and said:"System.NotSupportedException"

How can i fix this? Any ideas?

Here's the Connection Info for FTP.

```cs
private static string host = @"ftp://XXX.XX.XXX.XX/";
private static string user = "XXXXXXXX";
private static string pass = "XXXXXXXX";
private static string localfile = @"E:/Files/Attachment";
private static string remoteFile = @"D:/log/stdlog.6.txt";
```

And then FTP class

```cs
public class FtpServer
{
    private string host = null;
    private string user = null;
    private string pass = null;
    private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
    private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
    private Stream ftpStream = null;
    private int bufferSize = 2048;

    /* Construct Object */
    public FtpServer(string hostIP, string userName, string password) { host = hostIP; user = userName; pass = password; }
    public  void Download(string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {

        try
        {

            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host+remoteFile);


            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user,pass);

            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;

            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();

            ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();

            FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);

            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

            try
            {
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    localFileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can see that you have the drive letter in the remote path `D:/log/stdlog.6.txt`that seems wrong. Normally the ftp server has a "root" directory relative to which you specify the remote path. Have you checked if you are able to download the file using an ftp application?

Comment: I tried the other way. I just used file name but result is same.

Comment: Connect to the ftp server using msdos and type `pwd` to see what is the relative path your. "D:\log" is not a valid one. Your remote path sould look like `folder/filename.txt` and your local path `E:\files\Attachment`

Comment: You have another problem, you are defining `ftpRequest.UseBinary = true` but trying to download a `.txt` (non binary file). If you had your paths right (I think you dont), once downloaded the file it would be not readable. For `.txt` files you should use `ftpRequest.UseBinary = false`

Comment: If you are unable to download the file with an ordinary ftp application (list of applicaitons: https://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-free-ftp-client) you are most likely not going to be able to download it using C#

Comment: Flagging for closing because looks like a symple typo (paths are wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Unable to connect to remote server could be several reasons.

**1)** you could be mistakenly typing the server address and pointing to a non-existing address.

**2)** The server is temporarily shut or down and you cannot access it.

**3)** You typed in wrong credentials for the server.

Either way, I suggest you to implement [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) in your code rather then using `close()` on every stream:

```
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

    using (ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {

            using (FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create))
            {

                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

                try
                {
                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        localFileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                 }

            }
        }
    }

ftpRequest = null;
```

Comment: Both his `localfile` and `remoteFile` variables have incorrect values, check the quiestion comments. BTW, +1 on the using proposal